# How to add year in sales order and invoice number

Tags: magento2, sales-order, sales-invoice

I like to get current year in my order and invoice number.

Now i'm getting order id example: "XX-000001" i need to get like "XX-190001" this (19) is current year that need to be change in dynamic.

Please let me know how to change?

Comment: Try this extension: https://github.com/augustash/magento2-module-sales-sequence-customordernumber

Comment: I don't like to add extension for a simple work

Comment: Refer this...i think you may get some advise

Comment: Try this extension https://marketplace.magento.com/webbytroops-module-custom-order-invoice-number.html

Comment: Hi @Gaurav I don't like to add extension

Answer (score 1):

Magento 2 get the increment sequencing information from `sales_sequence_profile` table for order/invoice/shipment etc. All the sequencing params like prefix, suffix are fetched from this table. You need to update prefix column from this table to current year as string. eg: "2019-". All further orders will have this as prefix.

**Option 1:** Manually change the prefix at start of every year from this table.

**Option 2 :** Write a cron job that will get executed once in a year. This cron job will change the value of `prefix` column to current year for your order meta_id record in `sales_sequence_profile`.

To know more about `sales_sequence_profile` table please refer http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-2-change-increment-id-prefix-suffix-start-value-step-pad-length-of-order-invoice-creditmemo-shipment/.

Hope this finds you helpful..

Answer (score 0):

Hi Just i add "date("y")" in module/sequnce.php file